# Converting a working CURL put command to Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I have a working curl command that uploads a csv on my local server to a remote Artifactory server which will host the csv. I have a need to convert it to Python using the requests library as I am trying to integrate it into a bigger script. I'm unable to get it to work in Python because I'm getting a "405" error. Does anyone have any idea how i could get it to work in Python please? My working curl code example is below:

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer fsdfsfsfsdvsdvsdvsviQ" -X PUT "http://art.test.lan/artifactory/report/test.csv" -T test.csv`

The code I created to convert the above working code using Python requests which is giving me 
 the 405 is below:

````
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer fsdfsfsfsdvsdvsdvsviQ',
}

url = 'http://art.test.lan/artifactory/report'
files = {'file': open('test.csv', 'rb')}

response = requests.post(url=url, files=files)
print(response) 
print(response.text)```
````

Comment: you can try `requests.put()`

Comment: Wow thanks! That did the trick to get me over the hump i was stuck on! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from above

"you can try requests.put()" – from techytushar took care of this issue